# how to implement zmsg_recv_nowait?

Tags: c, zeromq

CZMQ library provide `nowait` option for `zstr` and `zframe` classes(`zstr_recv_nowait()` and `zframe_recv_nowait()`), but there is nothing like `zmsg_recv_nowait()`. Is there any solution? Instead of using `zmq_msg_recv` with `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` flag. My code is:

```
zmq_pollitem_t items[] = { {sock, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0} };
zmq_poll(items, 1, 10);
/* now receive all pending messages */
while (1) {
    zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv(sock); /* this will block after the last message received */
    /* consume message here */
}
/* sending bunch of messages */
```

I'm doing asynchronous `REQ/REP`. Sending multiple requests then receive replies when they are ready. This code will block my application. Also it seems ugly to me to do one `zmq_poll`, receive one message and so on... because by the time `zmq_poll` returns, other replies had been arrived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the poll codes into the loop. Using poll for one socket is fine.

an example may help:

```
while (1) {
    /* now receive all pending messages */
    zmq_pollitem_t items[] = { {sock, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0} };

    /* this will block for 10msec, ZMQ_POLL_MSEC is for compatibility for v2.2 */
    int rc = zmq_poll(items, 1, 10 * ZMQ_POLL_MSEC );
    if (rc == -1)
      break; // some error occured, check errno...

    if (items [0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
      /* there's something to receive */
      zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv(sock);
    }

    /* sending bunch of messages */
}
```

Comment: To clarify, use zmq_poll to check when the socket is ready for input and then recv on ready sockets only. The NOWAIT option is ugly since it means your code is manually looping, sleeping, etc. zmq_poll is a cleaner approach. The Guide has many examples of this.